# Wordress: How to exclude a category from Blog post page in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am looking for a way to exclude the category from Blog post page. With a php code it is possible, but are there any ways to do the same only by using the Style CSS? Which code will work for it?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try? Please provide some code.

Comment: You need to be more specific and post what you have tried. This is also incredibly vague, and people who wants to help has to "guess" and come up with something out of thin air. Please elaborate your question with examples etc. etc. If we're talking hiding a basic element, then use your browser's element inspector (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome), and look what selector you can use to target that element and then try this type of CSS: `"selector_here"{ visibility: hidden !important; }`. As I said, it's hard to say much else from the information that you have given.

Comment: So I need to exclude a category from the main blog post page to have the category posts appear in the Nav menu. I have tried something similar like: <..category .blog-categoryname {
    display:none;
}>  also with category id

Comment: in compare to .blog .post-444 {
display: none;
} 
 That works only for separate posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding! I was looking for a CSS code since not having a possibility to use php in WP in my version and license. Yet, I found an answer from other resources that I will share.

For excluding a category from the Blog page, for example in order to make the category posts appear under the same category in the menu, the code below could be used. (Replace "category-name" with the name of your category).

```
body.blog article.category-category-name {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, include **post_class();** to the parent div.  It automatically adds post information including category.  Here's some [examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Examples).

Without example code, I don't know what you initially wrote so it may look something like:

```
<?php
 $the_query = new WP_Query(
   array(
     'posts_per_page' => 20
   )
 );
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
       <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

 <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

Then check the classes is generates and apply the css to them.